# How to change the polling interval in Newrelic platform

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

How can I change the polling interval from the default 60 s in the Newrelic platform plugin API? I am using the Ruby API, and I have some statistics to report that are lengthy to calculate and they cannot be completed in the default interval. I cannot find any relevant documentation on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this default value here:

https://github.com/newrelic-platform/newrelic_plugin/blob/fffddc35e9085d8320f893c6a1c10bd4103800d1/lib/newrelic_platform_binding/config.rb#L31

Units are in seconds.

It should be noted that New Relic is expecting data once per minute so you will have some drops in your graphs if you do not post once per minute. New Relic strongly suggests that if you change the polling time that you do not set it to a value greater than 300 seconds.

One alternative to changing the default is to report the same metric for multiple polling cycles. When you have a new metric to send update it and send that to New Relic.